# hidding table row from code behind in asp.net using ajax

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, ajax

I`m trying to hide and show a row from selection index from a drop down and i`m using ajax update panel to show some checkboxes in that row .
when i`m trying to hide the row my code is

```
trOptions.Attributes.Add("style", "display : none ; ");
```

where troptions is and id that i assigned to my table row

```
<tr id="trOptions" runat="server" >
```

i don`t know why it doesn`t get the style ?

Update
I also have an attribute command in the same section of my code that actualy work

```
checkboxlist.Enabled = false;
```

but this one is working with asp.net control attribute.

i even tried to hide the row with jquery like this

```
function HideControl() {
        jQuery("#trOptions").hide();
    };
```

and in code behind

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "blah", "HideControl();", true);
```

i don`t know why it`s not working , is it because i`m using script-manger for ajax and i added script manualy to my page >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because i put part of the table in update panel and when i put the whole table in update panel and used

```
TrOptions.visible = false ;
```

My problem solved !

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo. Replace displey with display.

Comment: thanks man , i corrected display and run the project again but that wasn`t work .i checked the element via browser but the style was not inserted there

Comment: i suspect this happens because of ajax partial update which i don`t realy understood it

Comment: Did you try trOptions.Visible = false; I would put that code in place of ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "blah", "HideControl();", true); That should hide the row.